Does Shaiva Siddhanta consider both Vedas and Agamas as authority or does it reject Vedas?
I have consulted certain Shaiva Siddhanta dikshitas and they said that both are authority.
However certain people on online forums were talking something else. So can some deekshit Shaiva Siddhanta clarify please whether both Veda and Agamas are authority in Shaiva Siddhanta?
